# Drupal and Joomla on the same windows machine, any issues?

Tags: drupal, joomla

For learning purposes I have installed Joomla on my local host using XAMPP for Apache/PHP/MySQL. I have it up and running and I have done some basic things with it. Now I would like to install Drupal which can also be installed on top of XAMPP. I'd like to run both systems on my one windows laptop for learning purposes. Does anyone have any experience doing this? Any issues using the same XAMPP instance? Do PHP settings collide? Do directory structures colide....etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install them in separated folders and in separated databases (just in case, otherwise you can define a table prefix as well), they should be able to co-exist without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have magento, drupal, and wordpress all on the same machine just in different folders inside my xampp/htdocs folder. Don't imagine adding joomla would be any different..

Answer (score 1):

Keep them in **different folders** and use **different databases** and you won't have a problem.